# Como crear un Trigger en mysql con WHERE

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo un problema, resulta que estoy aprendiendo a crear Trigger en mysql pero no puedo encontrar la forma en que lo necesito.

Tengo esta tabla, la cual se va llenando de registros todos los días con mayor frecuencia en las mañanas.

[image: Table]

Necesito crear un Trigger que actualice el **estado** a 2 cuando la fecha actual sea mayor a **fecha_reserva**(datetime) y la hora actual, sea mayor a **hora_reserva**(time).

pensé en que se podía ejecutar éste evento cada vez que exista un nuevo registro en la tabla. No se si es correcto.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_stado AFTER INSERT FOR EACH ROW UPDATE SET estado = 
2 WHERE datetime() > fecha_reserva && date() > hora_reserva;
```

La verdad es que estoy aprendiendo y me gustaría ayuda en la Query.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede hacer esto en un trigger. Según la documentación:

> Dentro de una función almacenada o trigger, no está permitido modificar una tabla que ya está siendo utilizada (para leer o escribir) por la sentencia que invocó la función o disparador.

Lo cual quiere decir que la tabla queda bloqueada cuando se estan insertando datos en ella, por lo que no puedes insertar una fila y actualizarla a la misma vez. A partir de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247590/mysql-trigger-set-values-for-new-row-and-update-another-in-the-same-table) respuesta, te propongo la siguiente solución:

**Crear un procedimiento almacenado, que inserte en la tabla de destino y a continuación, actualice la otra fila, todo en una transacción.
Con un procedimiento almacenado, manualmente confirmarás los cambios (insertar y actualizar).**

No he hecho esto en MySQL, pero [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974325/mysql-transaction-within-a-stored-procedure) parece un buen ejemplo.
Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Ohh! gracias bro.

Comment: Me alegro haberte ayudado! Pero no soy bro, soy sis jeje ;)  Saludos.

Comment: oh! muchas gracias señorita ;)

Comment: De nada, solo como una nota, tal y como dice el título de tu pregunta si se puede hacer, o sea sí puedes hacer un trigger con where, lo que este ejemplo específico que planteas, que es actualizar la misma tabla donde se está insertando, es lo que no puedes hacer con un disparador. Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como acertada, gracias y saludos!!